# Tricky Offset date within dataframe rows using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, group-by

I would like to add a new consecutive date row at the end of a new category based on a column. Ex. based on the Area column.

### Data

```
   Date         Start       End         Area    ID  Stat
   1/1/2022     2/1/2022    3/1/2022    NY      222 Y
   2/1/2022     3/1/2022    4/1/2022    NY      111 Y
   1/1/2022     2/1/2022    3/1/2022    CA      333 Y
   2/1/2022     3/1/2022    4/1/2022    CA      100 Y
```

### Desired

```
 Date          Start        End         Area    ID  Stat
 1/1/2022      2/1/2022     3/1/2022    NY      222 Y
 2/1/2022      3/1/2022     4/1/2022    NY      111 Y
 3/1/2022      4/1/2022     5/1/2022    NY      
 1/1/2022      2/1/2022     3/1/2022    CA      333 Y
 2/1/2022      3/1/2022     4/1/2022    CA      100 Y
 3/1/2022      4/1/2022     5/1/2022    CA
```

### Doing

SO member helped w this code, this works partial for me, as the dates are not offset:

```
# Convert the cols to datetime
c = ['Start', 'End']
df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

# drop the duplicates rows by Area while keeping only the last row
rows = df[[*c, 'Area']].drop_duplicates('Area', keep='last')

# Add a dateoffset of 1 day
rows[c] += pd.DateOffset(days=1)

# Concat the rows and sort index to maintain order
pd.concat([df, rows]).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. I am currently researching this.

Comment: Solution works for me :-) just replace `c` with `c = ['Date', 'Start', 'End']`

Comment: Will try again, but it appears to creates a duplicate of the row above. Will play around w it. Thank you. I wonder shouldn’t the ‘days’ be ‘months’ since it is the month that is offset? @ShubhamSharma

Comment: If you need months offeset then just replace `days` with `months` and also while parsing to datetime in first step use format parameter: `df[c] = df[c].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y')`

Comment: will try this today - trying to figure why the dates are not staggering for me @ShubhamSharma